# Parse json string provided as input parameter for exe C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

Hi I have an applicationn which i need to execute from run command:

```
D:\MyApplication.exe {\"mydllpath\":\"D:\\dll\",\"FilePath\":\"D:\\Input\\abc.doc\", \"Attribute\":\"word\"}
```

However, I am unable to extract the values in "mydllpath", "FilePath" and "Attribute", It shows errors while parsing.

> error: Unexpected end of content while loading JObject. Path 'mydllpath', line 3, position 0. 
>    code:

```
foreach (string arg in args)
{
    var x = JObject.Parse(arg);
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If escaping the JSON then you need to enclose it in a string

```
D:\MyApplication.exe "{\"mydllpath\":\"D:\dll\",\"FilePath\":\"D:\Input\abc.doc\", \"Attribute\":\"word\"}"
```

which will be received in the code as

```
{"mydllpath":"D:\dll", "FilePath":"D:\Input\abc.doc", "Attribute":"word"}
```

and allow for proper parsing.

```
var json = args[0];
var x = JObject.Parse(json);
```